# Make Windows Media Player Pause when Locking PC and Play again when Unlocked?

Tags: windows-media-player, autohotkey

As the title says I want to be able make Windows Media Player Pause when Locking my PC and Play again when I've Unlocked it.

Is this possible?

I did try to do this with this AutoHotKey Script:

```
;---------------------------------------------------------------
;Notify Lock\Unlock
;   This script monitors LockWorkstation calls
;
;   If a change is detected it 'notifies' the calling script
;      On Lock
;         This script will call function "on_lock()"
;      On Unlock
;         This script will call fucntion "on_unlock()"
;IMPORTANT: The functions "on_lock()" and "on_unlock()" DO NOT
;exist in this script, they are to be created in the script that
;calls notify_lock_unlock() (presumably your main script)
;---------------------------------------------------------------
;Re-purposed by WTO605
;Last edited 2009-08-18 16:34 UTC
;---------------------------------------------------------------
;Based on Winamp_Lock_Pause by MrInferno
;Posted: Fri Apr 21, 2006 4:49 am
;Source: http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic9384.html
;---------------------------------------------------------------
;Winamp_Lock_Pause was/is based on script codes from "shimanov"
;Posted: Thu Sep 15, 2005 12:26 am   
;Source: http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=5359
;Posted: Tue Dec 06, 2005 9:14 pm
;Source: http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6755
;---------------------------------------------------------------

;Initialize global constants
WTS_SESSION_LOCK      :=   0x7
WTS_SESSION_UNLOCK      :=   0x8
NOTIFY_FOR_ALL_SESSIONS   :=   1
NOTIFY_FOR_THIS_SESSION   :=   0
WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE   :=   0x02B1

notify_lock_unlock()
{
   Global WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE
   Global NOTIFY_FOR_ALL_SESSION

   hw_ahk := FindWindowEx( 0, 0, "AutoHotkey", a_ScriptFullPath " - AutoHotkey v" a_AhkVersion )

   OnMessage( WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE, "Handle_WTSSESSION_CHANGE" )

   success := DllCall( "wtsapi32.dll\WTSRegisterSessionNotification", "uint", hw_ahk, "uint", NOTIFY_FOR_ALL_SESSIONS )

   if( ErrorLevel OR ! success )
   {
      success := DllCall( "wtsapi32.dll\WTSUnRegisterSessionNotification", "uint", hw_ahk )
      ;If DLL registration fails, wait 20 seconds and try again
      Sleep, 20000
      notify_lock_unlock()
      ;MsgBox, [WTSRegisterSessionNotification] failed: EL = %ErrorLevel%
   }
   return
}

Handle_WTSSESSION_CHANGE( p_w, p_l, p_m, p_hw )
; p_w  = wParam   ;Session state change event
; p_l  = lParam   ;Session ID
; p_m  = Msg   ;WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE
; p_hw = hWnd   ;Handle to Window
{
   Global WTS_SESSION_LOCK
   Global WTS_SESSION_UNLOCK

   If ( p_w = WTS_SESSION_LOCK )
   {
      on_lock()
   }
   Else If ( p_w = WTS_SESSION_UNLOCK )
   {
      on_unlock()
   }
}

FindWindowEx( p_hw_parent, p_hw_child, p_class, p_title )
{
   return, DllCall( "FindWindowEx", "uint", p_hw_parent, "uint", p_hw_child, "str", p_class, "str", p_title )
}

notify_lock_unlock()
; Calls function "on_lock()" when computer is locked and "on_unlock()" when computer is unlocked

on_lock()
{
   Send, {Media_Play_Pause}
}

on_unlock()
{
   Send, {Media_Play_Pause}
}
```

which works nicely so long as I am playing something on media player. If it's paused, then it starts playing when I lock my PC.

I can't seem to find any command line options for Windows Media Player to Pause/Play.

Does anyone know how to get this script to work properly?
Or if you have a better idea on how to do this, please say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Try this little program.](http://lifehacker.com/5314349/monitores-updates-pauses-any-media-player-when-you-lock-your-pc)

For Chris F - It's a program that turns off your monitor, pauses your media player, and puts your IM programs on AFK when you lock your PC.

Comment: Bare links aren't considered that useful. Can you post some more information about this please.

Comment: It's a good program, but unfortunately if Media Player is paused, it plays it when I lock and pauses when I unlock...

Comment: Well that's unfortunate...let me check for something else.

Comment: According to the dev site for MonitorES, they have ID'd that issue and it's fixed in the next release.  I know it doesn't help you now, though.

Comment: That's OK. I'll wait until the next release... or I'll download the source and try fix the problem myself